# how do i fix issue regarding "npm -v" not working? I upgrade to angular 10 and everytime I use terminal this below error

Tags: node.js, npm

how do i fix issue regarding "npm -v" not working? I upgrade to angular 10 and everytime I use terminal this below error.

```
internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 976
throw err; ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
Require stack:
  -/usr/local / lib / node_modules / npm / bin / npm - cli.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 973: 15)
at Function.Module._load(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 855: 27)
at Module.require(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1033: 19)
at require(internal / modules / cjs / helpers.js: 72: 18)
at / usr / local / lib / node_modules / npm / bin / npm - cli.js: 19: 21
at Object. < anonymous > (/usr/local / lib / node_modules / npm / bin / npm - cli.js: 153: 3)
at Module._compile(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1144: 30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 1164: 10)
at Module.load(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 993: 32)
at Function.Module._load(internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 892: 14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: ['/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js']
}
```

`

Comment: Usually reinstalling is easier than 'fixing'.

Comment: thanks, @Chris! that is exactly what i did. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ic_dpGAqeBQ&t=36s